# Progress bar is running after get the placeholder's image using Glade library

Tags: android

I have a code where images will show on ViewPager and the images will come from the server. I am using Glide library, but when I am using it if there is no images on the server side, then it will show a single image by-default, but the progress bar is running until we goes back or close the app. Below is my code please check it.

```
public class SlidingImage_Adapter extends PagerAdapter {
private ArrayList<String> IMAGES;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context context;
ProgressBar progressBar;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

SessionManager session;
public String string_gender;

public SlidingImage_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> IMAGES) {
    this.context = context;
    this.IMAGES=IMAGES;
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
    //  ImageView imageLayout = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_slide_fragment, view, false);
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_slide_fragment, view, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image);

    // Session class instance
    session = new SessionManager(context);
    session.checkLogin();
    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    string_gender = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_GENDER);



    ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) item_view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    //This will help to load image and show progressBar
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(imageView, spinner, IMAGES.get(position));

    //you need to add this line
    view.addView(item_view);

    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return IMAGES.size();
}


@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);

}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState(){
    return null;
}



public class ImageLoader{

    public ImageLoader(ImageView imageView, final ProgressBar progressBar, String imagePath){


        if(string_gender.equalsIgnoreCase("male"))
        {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(imagePath)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.girl)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            //handle error
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).into(imageView);
        }
        else{
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(imagePath)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.boy)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            //handle error
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).into(imageView);
                }
              }
            }
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your GlideListener implementation of onException method add this line on both your conditions :

```
 @Override
public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
     progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     return false;
                            }
```

Comment: pleasure is all mine

Comment: I used this but if there is images on server then progress bar spring only little time and image are come later

Comment: i didn't understand

Comment: There are two condition for viewpager 1. There is images on server 2. No images on server. If there is images on server which takes time to upload on pager but the progress bar is visible only 7 to 10 second while images loaded after 20 to 25 second

Comment: Have u understand

Comment: Actually there is some problem on server side and website also takes time to login, so I think that's why the image takes time to upload. Tomorrow I will check again and tell you. Thanku boss

Comment: Yep It's working there was problem on server side thanku

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside on resource ready

```
if (imageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.girl).getConstantState())
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: make a context variable and use `context.getResources`